CustomScrollView an ListView scroll
I have such a CustomScrollView. In this section, the SliverFillRemaining section stores the TabBar's lists.
I want the app bar to rise and be fixed at the top when scrolling the ListView.builders here. Only when I use physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() and physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() do some problems occur.
physics: const When I do NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() 120 data should appear in the list. But it seems between 30-40. I want to see all the data of this.
physics: There are other problems when using AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(). In this case, the code scrolls in a small place. It does not bring up the AppBar. If I manually move it up from the AppBar, then the list scrolls. When you want to scroll down, it hides 30-40 px above.
My Code
I have checked the physics parts of TabBar and other places with scroll. but I have not been able to find and solve the source of the problems in any of them.
